# Implementing a header in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c, wrapper

I'm completely new to `Objective C` and I'm trying to use it to wrap a `C-library`. I have a `main.m` `wrap.m` and `wrap.h` files. From what I gather in the header file I included `@interface` and in the source file I will include `@implementation` However I'm not really understanding what to include in each of them. Right now my main file is:

```
int copy_data(struct archive *ar, struct archive *aw) {

    for (;;) {
        const void *buff;
        size_t size;
        off_t offset;

        int r = archive_read_data_block(ar, &buff, &size, &offset);
        if (r == ARCHIVE_EOF)
            return (ARCHIVE_OK);

        archive_write_data_block(aw, buff, size, offset);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        struct archive *a;
        struct archive *ext;
        struct archive_entry *entry;
        int flags;
        int r;

        /* Select which attributes we want to restore. */
        flags = ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_TIME;
        flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_PERM;
        flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_ACL;
        flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_FFLAGS;

        a = archive_read_new();
        archive_read_support_format_all(a);
        archive_read_support_compression_all(a);
        ext = archive_write_disk_new();
        archive_write_disk_set_options(ext, flags);
        archive_write_disk_set_standard_lookup(ext);
        r = archive_read_open_filename(a, argv[1], 10240);

        for (;;) {
            r = archive_read_next_header(a, &entry);
            if (r == ARCHIVE_EOF)
                break;

            r = archive_write_header(ext, entry);
            if (archive_entry_size(entry) > 0) {
                copy_data(a, ext);
            }

            archive_write_finish_entry(ext);
        }
        archive_read_close(a);
        archive_read_free(a);
        archive_write_close(ext);
        archive_write_free(ext);
        NSLog(@"No Issues");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

So far what I'm getting in my `wrap.h` file is:

```
typedef struct{
int *a;
int *ext;

}archive;

@interface main : NSObject

@property int flags;
@property int r;
```

I don't know if that is close to what I need to do, and I'm getting errors on my `ARCHIVE_EXTRACT` saying they are undeclared identifiers which I assume also have to go into my `wrap.h` file but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: You're coding C methods, not Objective-C methods.  No Objective-C object is being defined, so you code the .h as for C.  No @interface, no properties.

Comment: I'm making an Objective-C wrapper for my current code shown above so I do need Objective-C code

Answer (score 0):

If you start your project in Xcode using the CommandLineTool template, you can select your language to be "C" or "C++", so you wouldn't have to mess with Objective-C at all.

[image: You can do a project in C]

[image: main.c is the file here]

As for the .h file that you currently have, don't do "`@property`" or "`@interface`" for "`main`".  "`main`" is a C style function and not an Objective-C thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually interested in an objectivec solution, follow Michael Dautermann's instructions to start a new Command Line project but instead of Type C use the Foundation option.  This will give you a working main (just a regular c function).  Then select new->objective c class to create your wrap.h/wrap.m.  In the wrap.h you will pretty much exclusively be declaring your own objectivec public wrapper methods.  In the wrap.m, you'll be importing what you want to wrap, and defining your wrapper functions.

```
//
//  main.m
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "wrap.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        [wrap wrappedStuff];

    }
    return 0;
}

//
//  wrap.h
//


----------


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface wrap : NSObject
+ (void)wrappedStuff;
@end



//
//  wrap.m
//

#import "wrap.h"
#include "WhatImWrapping.h"

@implementation wrap

int copy_data(struct archive *ar, struct archive *aw) {

    for (;;) {
        const void *buff;
        size_t size;
        off_t offset;

        int r = archive_read_data_block(ar, &buff, &size, &offset);
        if (r == ARCHIVE_EOF)
            return (ARCHIVE_OK);

        archive_write_data_block(aw, buff, size, offset);
    }
}

+ (void)wrappedStuff
{
    struct archive *a;
    struct archive *ext;
    struct archive_entry *entry;
    int flags;
    int r;

    /* Select which attributes we want to restore. */
    flags = ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_TIME;
    flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_PERM;
    flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_ACL;
    flags |= ARCHIVE_EXTRACT_FFLAGS;

    a = archive_read_new();
    archive_read_support_format_all(a);
    archive_read_support_compression_all(a);
    ext = archive_write_disk_new();
    archive_write_disk_set_options(ext, flags);
    archive_write_disk_set_standard_lookup(ext);
    r = archive_read_open_filename(a, argv[1], 10240);

    for (;;) {
        r = archive_read_next_header(a, &entry);
        if (r == ARCHIVE_EOF)
            break;

        r = archive_write_header(ext, entry);
        if (archive_entry_size(entry) > 0) {
            copy_data(a, ext);
        }

        archive_write_finish_entry(ext);
    }
    archive_read_close(a);
    archive_read_free(a);
    archive_write_close(ext);
    archive_write_free(ext);
    NSLog(@"No Issues");
}
@end
```

Comment: Yes that is essentially what I did, my `main.m` is part of a C library, I just don't know what exactly to put in my wrap files

Comment: wrapping any c library in cocoa is basically trivial but your scenario is puzzling.  Is "your main" really "part of a C library"?  What is "@interface main : NSObject" in wrap.h all about?

Comment: I assumed I needed it, and it is part of the libarchive library